# Append in parsexml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need some help finishing my code because I'm having a bit of trouble getting the syntax correct. I have a parse XML and I am using append to display the data. I am also trying to do on click event to send data to google analytics but here where I cannot get it right. This is what I want to add onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" in the front end but I cannot add single quote in append.

this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://www.nomuraconnects.com/rss/articles",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXml
  });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
  $("#main").html("<div class='section group' id='content' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></div>");
  $(xml).find("item").slice(0, 2).each(function () {
      $("#content").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + $(this).find("link").text() + "' onclick='dataLayer.push({});'><div class='col span_1_of_2'><div class='thumbnail'><img src='" + $(this).find("enclosure").attr('url') + "'/></div><div class='text-box'><h2>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</h2><p>" + $(this).find("description").text() + "</p></div></div></a>");
  });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to set event handlers, HTML and attributes of dynamically created element.

```js
const dataLayer = [];

$("#content")
.append($("<a>",{
  target: "_blank" // set `target` attribute
, href: "javascript:void 0" // set `href` attribute
, html: "<div>parent div" // set `innerHTML`
       + "<div>child div 1<img alt='img'/></div>"
       + "<div>child div 2<h2>h2</h2><p>p</p></div></div>"
, on: { // set event handlers
       click: function(e) { // set `click` event
                dataLayer.push({"event": "button1-click"});
                console.log(dataLayer);
              }
      }
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:25% !important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, all the data is coming from the xml in my previous method I was getting the href by using this +$(this).find("title").text()+ in your method how do I get the data?

Comment: @JosephZammit Have you tried using the same approach `href:$(this).find("title").text()`?

Comment: Yes, thanks this worked perfectly. On the click function if I want to collect the url clicked how do i do that?

Comment: @JosephZammit `this.href` that is set at the code should be the URL clicked